# WiFi adapter not found Ubuntu 18.04 Dell Latitude 5400

Tags: networking, 18.04, drivers, wireless, dell

Since morning, my system is not able to detect Wireless adapter. I've explored a bunch of fixes suggested in similar problems but none has worked so far for me.

```
 sudo lshw -c network
*-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 32
       serial: c0:b5:d7:b3:aa:77
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.15.0-1087-oem firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:138 memory:91000000-911fffff
```

```
nmcli device show wlp2s0 
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         C0:B5:D7:B3:AA:77
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
```

```
rfkill list
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
lspci -k | grep -A 4 -i "Network controller"
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Dell QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

```
cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

```
dmesg | grep wlp
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and also: `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and finally: `dmesg | grep wlp`  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555, updated.

Comment: No useful clues so far. Let's see what the PCI bus is doing: `dmesg | grep 02:00` and also let's see what the driver is doing: `dmesg | grep ath` Please add the results as edits to your question.